# How to convert a pytorch Dataset object to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I have a pandas dataframe called df that I split into train/test sets using the random_split function from torch library.

```
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, random_split

df = pd.read_csv('some_txt_file.txt', sep= ' ')
len_test = len(df) // 10
len_train = len(df) - len(test)
lengths = [len_train, len_test]
train, test = random_split(df, lengths, torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
```

Is there a way to convert these Dataset objects back into pandas dataframes? I tried

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame(train)
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

but it throws the error

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`torch.utils.data.random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) will return [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset), which is composed of `dataset` and `indices`.

To get the sub dataframe, you can do

```py
df_train = train.dataset.iloc[train.indices]
# or
df_train = df.iloc[train.indices]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works if you replace loc with iloc though.

Comment: @CoolMathematician You are right, the `indices` is range from `[0, len(df))`, using `iloc` is more robust.